# Who do I contact regarding DA not charging sexual assault offender

Tags: sexual-assault, disabilities, police-power

I was sexually assaulted which injured hip and psoas muscle, told DHHS bc im and was disabled & offender was DHHS CWS , filed police report 5-29-21 a year later Salem crime survivors a lady named Shawna called to inform "DAnot enough evidence " Shocked I began calling, tweeting & podcasts DA Mckintok speaks to me & informed me deputy ritz did the "investigation " I spoke to ritz 'why didn't you " all he said is "ok " 5x I ask why he said I want to argue, no I want justice, he then said "I recorded our interview " I said'push play' to no avail so again public appeal via calls tweets podcast so then ritz "redo" then another year no words so call DA again no charge

Comment: Voting to close because this question is barely legible and it needs to be cleaned up with proper grammar and spelling.

Answer (score 5):

A district attorney has discretion to decide whether to prosecute.
A district attorney may be appointed by e.g. a county board of commissioners, or they may be elected. The electorate has the exclusive power to chastise DA, but voting him out of office, so there is little to be done other than write letters to the editor. An appointed DA has some superior, so you can complain to that superior. There is no way to legally force a DA to prosecute if they do not believe that there is enough evidence to get a conviction.

Comment: If the decision was made by a deputy DA an appeal to his boss, the actual DA is worth considering.